# Token funeral is held

Tags: phrase-meaning

Recently I have come across a sentence: “A token funeral is held. There is nothing to bury.” I couldn’t find an explanation what a token funeral is.

This is all the context that there is about the “token funeral”. I assume it means a funeral, without the remains, as they cannot be found.

Comment: Look up *token* as an adjective.

Comment: Please add more context—did this sentence appear all by itself, or were there other sentences around it that might help us figure out what it means? "Token funeral" is not an expression in general use in English, so you will have to figure it out from what the individual words mean and from context.

Comment: Was the bereaved missing at sea? Lost in an air-crash? Blown up? Please add context.

Comment: Look up "token effort", 'token payment", "token friend", et al.  (Ie, put some sort of token effort into researching this.)

Comment: **token** is a bad word choice.  It's not the *mot juste*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a little more context.  This comes from [*Watchmen*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0409459/) where nuclear physicist Doctor Jonathan Osterman is disintegrated in a accident in a laboratory.  There is no body for a traditional funeral and so a token funeral is held instead to mark his death, as you assumed; contrast this with the Comedian's real funeral in the same film.

Here *token* means something minor representing the real thing.

As often seems to happen with movie funerals without a body, Jon is not actually dead and instead reconstructs himself to become [Doctor Manhattan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Manhattan) with superhuman nuclear-related powers.

Comment: But can you explain why the word 'token' is used for this situation?

Comment: @Mitch: I had thought that had been understood as something minor representing the real thing

Comment: You should add that into your answer as the question asks about the particular word 'token' and your answer does not address it directly.